# how to create the table（column family） for file input and output

Tags: cassandra

[how to read file from cassandra and write file to cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207868/how-to-read-file-from-cassandra-and-write-file-to-cassandra)

From the link above, I got the way to read and write file with Cassandra, but I don't know the structure of the table.

The code below is the way to insert file into Cassandra. I guess that  `filename` and `file`
are two columns (is it "filename" the primary key?). What is the type for `file` when we write `CREATE TABLE (...,...,...)` .Is "blob" ok?

```
 ByteBuffer fileByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( readFileToByteArray( filename ) );
 Statement insertFile = QueryBuilder.insertInto( "files" ).value( "filename", filename ).value( "file", fileByteBuffer );
    session.execute( insertFile );
```

I create the columnfamily :

```
            "CREATE TABLE " + columnfamily + " ("
            + PK+ " varchar PRIMARY KEY," 
            + " password varchar ,"
            + " file blob"
            + ");";
```

I do the query:

```
 Statement insertFile = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace + "."+columnfamily)
 .value(PK, "LDCR.lua").value("file", fileByteBuffer).value("password", "654321");
 session.execute(insertFile);
```

but it says:

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily

Comment: Can you paste your actual CQL statement and not the java code? The error is telling you that the CF doesn't exist. Also if I'm interpreting your `create table` statement correctly your PK is a value rather than a column name.

Comment: I have solve this problem `insertInto(keyspace , columnfamily)`. but I find that the bytes taken from Cassandra have extra header??